# Angular. Authentication is not checked

Tags: angularjs

Authentication is not checked in my angular app. User should not have access to "car" & "profile" views without login but now i can get to it. I've added "secure" property to the pages that should be hidden from non-authenticated user. I've added check for apprun in app.js. But it does not work.

here's **services.js**

```
    'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
.service('carsSrv', function () {
  var carList = [];

  var addUserCar = function (currObj, title, color, description, image) {
    currObj = {
        title: title,
        color: color,
        descriptiopn: description,
        image: image
      };
      /* console.log("Car Added:  " + currObj.id + "\n" + currObj.title + "\n" + currObj.color + "\n" + currObj.description + "\n" + currObj.image);*/
    carList.push(currObj);
    console.log(carList);
  };

  var getCars = function () {
    console.log("User cars");
    console.log(carList);
    return carList;

  };

  return {
    addUserCar: addUserCar,
    getCars: getCars
  }


})
.service('userSrv', userSrv)
.provider('storageSrv',storageSrv);
    function userSrv(storageSrv, carsSrv) {
      var user = {name: '', cars: carsSrv.carList };
      this.getUser = function() {
          return user;
      };

      this.getUserName = function () {
          return user.name;
      };
      this.login = function(){
        user.name = 'test name';
        user.cars = init();
        storageSrv.updateData(user);
                return true;

      }
      this.logout = function(){
        user.name = '';
        user.cars = [];
        alert('User logs out');
        storageSrv.updateData(user);
      }
      this.checkLoginUser = function(){
        return user.name !='';
      }
      this.getUserFeatures = function(){
        return user.features;
      }
      this.registration = function(){
        user.name = name;
        user.cars = init();
      }
      function init(){
        return storageSrv.getData();
      }

    }



  function storageSrv(){
    var storageName = 'cars';
    return {
      configStorageName : configStorageName,
      $get:$get
    };

    function configStorageName(name){
      if(name){
        storageName = name;
        return this;
      }
      else{
        return storageName;
      }
    }

    function $get(){
      function updateStorage(data){
        localStorage.setItem(storageName, data);
      }
      function getStorage(){
        return localStorage.getItem(storageName);
      }
      function updateData(data){
        console.log('storageName ' + storageName);
        updateStorage(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
      function getData(){
        console.log('storageName ' + storageName);
        var data = getStorage();
        return JSON.parse(data) || [];
      }
      return {
        updateData: updateData,
        getData:getData
      }
    }
  };
```

and here's **app.js**

```
    'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
])
    .constant('STORAGE_NAME', 'USER_CARS')
    .config(configStorage)
    .config(configRoutes)

.controller('carsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'carsSrv',
    function($scope, $http, carsSrv) {
        $scope.view = "Cars";
        $http.get('cars/cars.json')
            .success(function(data) {

                $scope.cars = data;

                $scope.addCar = function(id, title, color, description, image) {
                    carsSrv.addUserCar(id, title, color, description, image);
                };

            })
            .error(function() {
                alert("can not get data from cars.json");
            });
    }
])

.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope',

    function($scope) {
        $scope.view = "Home";
    }
])

.controller('loginCtrl', ['userSrv', '$scope',
    function(userSrv, $scope) {
        $scope.view = "Login";
        $scope.userLogin = function() {
            userSrv.login();

        }
        $scope.userLogout = function() {
            userSrv.logout();

        }

    }
])

.controller('profileCtrl', ['$scope', 'carsSrv',
    function($scope, carsSrv) {
        $scope.view = "Profile";
        $scope.userCars = carsSrv.getCars();


    }
]);

function configStorage(storageSrvProvider, STORAGE_NAME) {
    console.log(storageSrvProvider);
    storageSrvProvider.configStorageName(STORAGE_NAME);
}

function configRoutes($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/cars', {
        templateUrl: 'views/cars.html',
        controller: 'carsCtrl',
        secure: true
    })

    .when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
        controller: 'profileCtrl',
        secure: true
    })

    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        secure: false
    })

    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        secure: false
    })



    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}

var appRun = function($rootScope, $location, $userSrv) {
    $rootScope.on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next) {
        if (next.secure && !userSrv.checkLoginUser()) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your not really running the code `appRun`. Try adding this last line to your module declaration:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
])
    .constant('STORAGE_NAME', 'USER_CARS')
    .config(configStorage)
    .config(configRoutes)
    .run(appRun);
```

Also, because `appRun` is a variable containing an anonymous function, and not a function named appRun, by the time you call the `run(appRun)` (at the beginning of the file) the variable is defined but still `undefined`. That is why the function is not running.

Also, when listening to the event, you're using a function `$rootScope.on()`, instead of the correct name `$rootScope.$on()`. Apart from that, I tested it on my computed and it seems to be working.

```
function checkRoute ( userSrv, $location, current ) {
    if (current.secure && !userSrv.checkLoginUser()) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }
}

function appRun ($rootScope, $route, $location, userSrv) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next) {
        checkRoute(userSrv, $location, next);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('sessionLogout', function () {
        checkRoute(userSrv, $location, $route.current);
    });
};
```

**Update**: For the logout to work, one strategy is to emit an event when logging out and then listen for that even and do the same check to see if the page is secure or not.

```
function userSrv($rootScope, storageSrv, carsSrv) {
    //...
    this.logout = function(){
        user.name = '';
        user.cars = [];
        alert('User logs out');
        storageSrv.updateData(user);

        // Emit an event notifying the application that
        // the user has logged out
        $rootScope.$emit('sessionLogout');
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: I've added. now I have this "angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
])
    .constant('STORAGE_NAME', 'USER_CARS')
    .config(configStorage)
    .config(configRoutes)
    .run(appRun)

.controller('carsCtrl'....." - it does not help

Comment: Not for app. just 404 for favicon

Comment: Ok. You need to either declare the appRun var before using it or declaring it as a funcion (because functions are hoisted in javascript). Check my updated answer to see if it works now.

Comment: Great! login() works correctly, but logout() does not work

Comment: Added a solution to handle logout. Not sure this is what you want. Basically you have to re-run the route validation after logout.